# How create an Admin to manage users on two independent Firebase projects with a shared DB

Tags: firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication

**Problem**

I have two seperate apps, a "Manager" app and an "Employee" app which share a database, and I am using Firebase for auth.  Currently I have two different projects in Firebase, one for each user type. I am now trying to develop a third "Admin" app that allows someone appointed by the organization to manage users on both the "Employee" and "Manager" apps.  I have looked into using custom claims but in order for this to work across both apps would have to be on the same Firebase project.

**Potential Solutions**

1. ***Migrate all users to the same Firebase project***
   In this case, I migrate all of the users to one Firebase project and would assign a type to each user.  Upon login, I would check if they are of the right type for that application and log them out if they are not - it's a bit hacky but workable
2. ***Switch auth providers***
   Obviously the most tedious and costly option that I would like to avoid if possible

Can anyone help me figure out the best approach here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since all three apps seems to work within the same domain, it'd be most common to set them up in a single project and use custom claims, security rules, or a combination of both to control access of the various user types.